# $i(w^2 +w^{-2})-(w-w^{-1}) = i$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

How do we solve the following equation?

$$i(w^2 +w^{-2})-(w-w^{-1}) = i$$

where $w = e^{ix}$ and $i$ is a complex number.

Answer (score 2):

You have $\cos 2x-\sin x=\frac12$, and recall double angle formula for cosine.

Alternatively, note that $w^2+w^{-2}=(w-w^{-1})^2+2$, and solve the quadratic in $w-w^{-1}$, hence $w$.

Comment: That makes sense! Is there another approach, too?

Comment: Small correction: you need a quadratic in $w-\frac 1 w$

Comment: Oops, thank you @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Is there any reason to believe any of the four solution satisfy $|w|=1$ as suggested by $w=e^{i\theta}$?

Comment: @Henry There is no reason why $w=e^{ix}$ means $\lvert w\rvert=1$, since we have not imposed $x\in\mathbb{R}$ *a priori*.